# put a banner before the container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

**Hello !**

I have been sent this mockup and the HTML of this container and I am asked to style it.

But I am struggling to put that blue banner behind this container with content, if anyone has an idea of how I can achieve this please help me because I have a close deadline.

**Can anyone please help me here?**

[image: screenshot]

```css
  
.pj-container {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 39px;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.pj {
  $p_j: &;
  &--wrapper {
    #{$p_j} {
      &__title {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
      &__card {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #d6d7dc;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: rgba(241, 242, 246, 0.22);
        padding: 18px 24px 20px !important;
      }
      &__list {
        li {
          font-weight: bold;
          counter-increment: mylistcounter;
        }
        li::before {
          background-color: #fddf36;
        }

        span::before {
          display: inline-block;
          content: counter(mylistcounter) " . ";
          margin-right: 5px;
        }
      }
      &__amount {
        color: #02afbc !important;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        line-height: 32px;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="paragraph-block__block">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block__content">
          <div class="mt-4 pj-container container">
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus. Cursus sit amet dictum sit amet. Egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis. Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat. Dolor morbi non arcu risus. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere.

Aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna. Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel. Fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros. Nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id. Amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec feugiat. Morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra. Eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo. Nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae. Tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a pseudo element for the `.pj-container` `::before` for the banner. Define ***width***, ***height***,  ***background-color***, ***top*** and ***left*** properties with a ***z-index*** of **-1**; to place it behind your text container.

You can make your pseudo element `.pj-container::before` **position absolute** and place it at **top: 0** and **left: 0**. Place a ***top-margin*** on your `pj-container` to push down further below the top of the top fold.

```css
.pj-container::before  {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #02b4bd;
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.pj-container {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 39px;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.pj {
  $pieces_justificatives: &;
  &--wrapper {
    #{$pieces_justificatives} {
      &__title {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
      &__card {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #d6d7dc;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: rgba(241, 242, 246, 0.22);
        padding: 18px 24px 20px !important;
      }
      &__list {
        li {
          font-weight: bold;
          counter-increment: mylistcounter;
        }
        li::before {
          background-color: #fddf36;
        }

        span::before {
          display: inline-block;
          content: counter(mylistcounter) " . ";
          margin-right: 5px;
        }
      }
      &__amount {
        color: #02afbc !important;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        line-height: 32px;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="paragraph-block__block">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block__content">
          <div class="mt-4 pj-container container">
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus. Cursus sit amet dictum sit amet. Egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis. Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat. Dolor morbi non arcu risus. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere.

Aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna. Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel. Fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros. Nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id. Amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec feugiat. Morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra. Eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo. Nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae. Tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to make the banner as a ::before for the parent div instead of adding a new div?

Answer (score 2):

**This is how its done. Let me know if this works or if this is what you wanted?**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f8f8f9;
  
  /* Aligning overlay center using "grid-method" */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px; /* change height accordingly */
  background: blue;
}

.overlay {
  width: 90%; /* change height accordingly */
  height: 80%; /* change height accordingly */
  max-width: 400px; /* change height accordingly */
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="banner"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**SORRY FOR LATE EDIT** : but you can also achieve the same using `:before` pseudo element as you said.

**Check this one**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.background {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.background::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px; /* change accordingly */
  background-color: teal;
}

.background .overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

[@dale landry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533592/dale-landry) already answered your question very well.

Comment: This is really helpful but what if I want to but the banner as a ::before for the overlay div, is that possible to do?

Comment: *"This is how its done. Let me know if this works or if this is what you wanted?"* ? Would be better you described in short the changes you made instead of *"This is it! Does this answers?"* stuff.